# Android Studio 1.0 Error

Tags: java, android, ide

So far I have updated to Android 1.0 and some of my issues where fixed but the Gradle issue is driving me nuts. I have searched everywhere and none of the solutions work for me I use Windows 8.1

When ever I try to run my program:
Pops up

> Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause:

However the virtual Android still runs and the project is not there and this pops up:

```
19:32:30 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 9 sec
19:37:15 Unexpected Error
         Local path doesn't exist.
Local path doesn't exist.
The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
         Sync Project with Gradle files
19:37:15 Session 'app': error
19:38:29 Gradle build finished in 4 sec
19:44:14 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 3 sec
19:45:16 Unexpected Error
         Local path doesn't exist.
Local path doesn't exist.
The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
         Sync Project with Gradle files
19:45:16 Session 'app': error
```

I try to open Android SDK it wont open I tried to solve that as well by editing android.bat running as admin updating java reinstall everything. Nothing works.

Comment: also tried -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m did not work

Comment: aswell as Try this. It helped me, FINALLY !!!

*close android studio *Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6 * goto \sdk * rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup) * extract this zip to \sdk * it will make tools folder in \sdk *restart studio and errors will be gone

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388. Comment #33 in there has something which may help you.